# Laravel Sanctum with ReactJS SPA returns 401 Unauthorized after successful login

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, axios, laravel-sanctum

I can't find where am I wrong, I'm trying to retrieve user data from server, but 401 error returned instead. Route is protected with middleware, but after successful login it is still unauthorized, what could cause this or where am I missing something?

```
// ReactJS

 const http = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
headers: {
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
},
withCredentials: true
});

async function getUser() {
const csrf = await http.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
const login = await http.post('/login', {
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    password: 'secret'
})
 const user = await http.get('/api/user')
}

useEffect(() => {
  getUser();
},[]);
```

Here is the laravel things

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1:8000 // 8000 is laravel port
```

Route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

Cors

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],
'supports_credentials' => true
```

Comment: login api should return a "TOKEN", and after login you should pass that token as "Bearer auth token" in header in next request

Comment: @EstailSe Life saver, I couldn't find this information with bearer tokens, thanks.

Comment: As per the docs, first party SPA's (like a React app) shouldn't use a bearer token. They should prefer using session based auth